# HTML, Iframes with PHP?

Tags: php, html, iframe, include, ssi

I know of the **include()** code, but I want the iframes to change. 
In HTML it would be something like

```
 <A href="mickeymouse.html" target="NAME_OF_THE_IFRAME">Mickey</A>
```

How can I do the same in PHP?

Also for static HTML is it better to use include() or get_content()? What do you usually use?

What I'm trying to do is a more SEO-friendly and simpler website.

Comment: just start a php tag and echo the name of your iframe i.e.  target="<?php echo $iframeUrl ; ?>" >Mickey</a>

Comment: You can output the very same HTML snippet from a PHP script. You can not have PHP invoke a browser-side frame change. You need to explain your setting and what you are trying to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename you file from html to php, and then change your line for the following one

```
<? $myIframeURL = "whateveryouwant" ?>   //Here you can define the url you want to load 
<A href="mickeymouse.html" target="<?= $myIframeURL  ?>">Mickey</A>
```

Comment: don't use php shorttags, it's a bad practice and server dependent

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$varri = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416527/html-iframes-with-php"; 
?> 

  <iframe src=<?php print $varri; ?> scrolling="auto" width=100% height=100% frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```